# How do I make this php script add a line to data.txt or make it write to a different

Tags: php, variables, save, user-input, save-as

I have a php script for userinput and now I would like this script to "add to existing file data.txt (preferred)" or make a seperate file for each answer named $field1

```
<?php
$txt = "data.txt";
$fh = fopen($txt, 'w+');
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both fields are set
 $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'];
 file_put_contents('data.txt',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND); //log to data.txt
 exit();
}
 fwrite($fh,$txt); // write information to the file
 fclose($fh); // close the file

?>
```

It's a form on the website that has to write

```
"Name - Vote"
"Name - Vote"
"Name - Vote"
```

Right now it overrides the file instead of adding to it

Comment: Can u post what you are working on. Driving blind over here?

Comment: It's a form on the website that has to write
"Name - Vote"
"Name - Vote"
"Name - Vote"

Right now it overrides the file instead of adding to it

Comment: Your code is has logical errors

Answer (score 0):

@Eric: Read the comments inserted in the code for resolution

```
<?php
$txt = "data.txt";
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); // the correct open flag for append end of file
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both fields are set
 $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'];
 fwrite($fh, $txt . "\n"); // carriage return added (*assumption needed)
 // exit(); // omit
}
 // fwrite($fh,$txt); // write information to the file // pointless, redundant
 fclose($fh); // close the file

?>
```